# libmicrohttpd ./configure: pthreads not supported (osx)

Tags: macos, pthreads, osx-lion, configure, include-path

After downloading and untarballing `libmicrohttpd` from the GNU archive, I did the usual: `./configure`. However, `configure` stopped reporting an error. Here are the last few relevant lines:

```
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
checking if compiler supports -pthread... no
checking if compiler supports -pthreads... no
checking if compiler supports -threads... configure: error: Your system is not supporting pthreads!
```

I searched online, and sure enough, it appears that OSX **does** have `pthreads`, however I could not find anything on `configure` reporting errors about no pthreads on OSX.

Here is a top level `ls` of my `/usr/include`: http://sprunge.us/DGgY

and here is a `tree` of the same: http://sprunge.us/fVBV

Comment: Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) instead of trying to build from scratch - I just checked and they have a formula for libmicrohttpd.

Comment: @PaulR That worked, except for one thing: how do I get the header files to show up in `/usr/include`?

Comment: They are in /usr/local/include - gcc will find them there, or you can add this to your include paths (-I).

Comment: Cool. Could you put this in an answer so I can mark it correct? Thanks @PaulR !

Comment: Sure - consider it done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X it's easier to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) instead of trying to build from scratch - I just checked and they have a formula for `libmicrohttpd`.

Note that by default Homebrew puts headers and libraries under `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` - gcc will find libraries and headers here by default, or you can add the paths explicitly if you prefer (`-I` for include paths, `-L` for library paths).